PrimeNG table FrozenColumns and Sticky Header don't work well together
I need to migrate primeng 9 to primeng 17, and I ran into a problem.
Since they changed how the table works and it is not separate anymore for frozen columns/rows. It causes a problem where you can't have frozen columns and a sticky header.
I want to be able to have a table that has an internal horizontal scrollbar -> meaning a max-width.
But i also want the table to have no max-height, meaning the headers would be sticky.
This stackblitz explains what scrolling behaviour I want when scrolling vertically. The problem is the scrolling behaviour horizontally. I want the navbar to stay in place, without setting it to fixed.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/5h7dfz?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-frozen-columns-demo.html
If i delete this code from the styles.scss, i get the correct horizontal scrolling behavior. But not the correct vertical behaviour.

.p-datatable-wrapper {
  overflow: visible;
}

